# Solving for an Unknown Vector Magnitude and Angle with Known Vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

I have been stumped by this question and can not find anything online that could help me solve this problem.

> At a picnic, there is a contest in which hoses are used to shoot water
>   at a beach ball from three directions. As a result, three forces act
>   on the ball, F with arrow1, F with arrow2, and F with arrow3 (see
>   drawing). The magnitudes of F with arrow1 and F with arrow2 are F1 =
>   35.0 newtons and F2 = 80.0 newtons. Using a scale drawing and the graphical technique determine the following such that the resultant
>   force acting on the ball is zero.

[image]

Here is what i have done: I set shifted the vectors over to create a head to tail arrangement. I was able to figure out that the angle inbetween the two known magnitudes was 60 degrees. (based off the problem.) Then I used the SAS rule of cosigns to find the magnitude.

a^2=b^2+C^2-2(b)(c)cos(&)
f3= 50^2+90^2-2(50)(90)cos(60)

F3= 45.03

I have not tried the angle yet. But that it wrong, is there any other way to solve this problem more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

If the net force is zero then the net horizontal force and net vertical force will be zero.

So,

```
F1.sin6o = F3.sin0 (Net vertical force)

F2 = F1.cos6o + F3.cos0 (Net horizontal force)
```

Comment: so that will help get the x and y components, thus allowing me to find the magnitude?

Comment: If the value of theta can be known then you will surely get your answer. The reason is that the ball is not moving so the net force must be zero. So you divide the forces on the ball in two components 1 in x axis and 1 in y axis and equate all the forces to zero keeping in mind the direction of the forces.

Comment: Sorry for being ignorant, but i am not following. So you are telling me to break each force into an x and y component? I can not seem to wrap my head around this. Physics is not my thing.

Comment: Each vector is a xy plane is a resultant of two vectors in the same plane but one of them lies on x-axis and another on y-axis. Its the different combination of different magnitudes of these vectors that leads to a formation of a new vector when these are added.

Comment: So if you find the resultant of the two vectors F1.cos60 and F1.sin60 (which are the two vectors along x and y axis respectively that vectorially sum up to F1) then you will find that the resultant is equal to F1 (The resultant can be found by the formula that you used in your question). So it is absolutely valid to break a vector into two different vectors whose resultant will give you the vector that you initially broke. So in your question i broke the vectors along x and y axes.

Comment: So maybe something like this. F3x = f1x^2+f2x^2-2fx..... and so forth with the y axis. Then do a sqrt(f3x^2+f3y^2) to get the magnitude, and the angle comes from the the "triangle" That is made with the x components ?